# Order of magnitude of when vmstat's swap si/so must be considered unhealthy?

Tags: performance, swap

With `vmstat` I can see in the swap si/so columns how many blocks are read/written from/to the swap per second. I have a system with tight memory and therefore need to make use of the swap. Which is fine, since nearly all software has some bytes in RAM that it does not really use. Having these lingering on swap does not harm.

But when do I have to accept that the system is in an unhealthy state with too much swap activity. Is si=10, so=0 already a problem? What about a burst of si=100, so=500 for example? Are there any rules of thumb as to when one finally has to get more RAM other than waiting for users to complain?

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to call:

```
vmstat -s
```

and have a look at the `revolutions of the clock hand` line and check the value.

If this number is no more than one per day of uptime, there is sufficient RAM.

BTW: This only works on UNIX! Linux does not have that value. It may be an option to tell the Linux kernel people that it is missing on Linux..